# Apache Configuration Ubuntu 14.04 on local machine

Tags: spring-mvc, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I have just updated Apache from 2.2 to 2.4. But my Apache settings are not working for my site on my local machine. Here are the details

```
<VirtualHost www.letscompete.it:80>

    ServerName www.letscompete.it

    DocumentRoot /opt/content/letscompete-content/velocity/static/

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyTimeout 1000
    TimeOut 1000

    # Proxy requests to the java application
    # trailing slash required at the end of context path or will end up in a redirect loop  
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/letscompete/

    # Revrites http headers (Location, Content-Location, URI) 
    # on http redirect responses to avoid bypassing this gateway
        # in redirects coming from the web application
    # no trailing slash at the end of context path (optional)
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/letscompete

    # Adjusts the Path string in Set-Cookie headers
    # NOTE: no trailing slash at the end of context path or will have redirect (302) issues after authentication
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /letscompete /

    # Filters output HTML to convert the context path
        # generated from the proxyied server to the one
        # on this proxy
    SetOutputFilter proxy-html

    # NOTE: trailing slash required at the end of context path or links will be generated without the context
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /letscompete/ /

    ProxyHTMLDocType "<!DOCTYPE html>"

    AllowEncodedSlashes On

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico$                      /images/favicon.ico [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/bootshop/(.*)$ /bootshop/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/less/(.*)$ /less/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/css/(.*)$ /css/$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/img/(.*)$ /img/$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [NC,L]    
    RewriteRule ^/js/(.*)$ /js/$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/font/(.*)$ /font/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/letscompete/(.*)$ /$1 [R]

    <Directory "/opt/content/FindBlog-content/velocity/static/">
         Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride None
          Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<Proxy ajp://localhost:8009>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Proxy>
```

Whenever I hit this address the server throws the error:

> Service Unavailable
>   The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

I have enabled the following modes:

access_compat alias auth_basic authn_core authn_file authz_core authz_host authz_user autoindex deflate dir env filter mime mpm_event negotiation proxy proxy_ajp proxy_express proxy_html proxy_scgi proxy_wstunnel rewrite setenvif status xml2enc

Here is my error log:

```
[Sat Nov 21 10:49:29.130742 2015] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 1833:tid 140289415259904] (104)Connection reset by peer: AH01030: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header  
[Sat Nov 21 10:49:29.130904 2015] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 1833:tid 140289415259904] [client 127.0.0.1:45935] AH00992: ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed  
[Sat Nov 21 10:49:29.130920 2015] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 1833:tid 140289415259904] (120006)APR does not understand this error code: [client 127.0.0.1:45935] AH00878: read response failed from
127.0.0.1:8009 (localhost)  
[Sat Nov 21 10:49:31.731353 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 1832:tid 140289318573824] AH00940: AJP: disabled connection for (localhost)  
[Sat Nov 21 10:49:32.604179 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 1833:tid 140289310181120] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: AJP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 (localhost) failed  
[Sat Nov 21 10:49:32.604230 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 1833:tid 140289310181120] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 60s  
[Sat Nov 21 10:49:32.604244 2015] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 1833:tid 140289310181120] [client
127.0.0.1:45948] AH00896: failed to make connection to backend: localhost  
[Sat Nov 21 10:49:33.322966 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 1833:tid 140289301788416] AH00940: AJP: disabled connection for (localhost)  
[Sat Nov 21 10:49:39.384979 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 1833:tid 140289293395712] AH00940: AJP: disabled connection for (localhost)
```

And as for my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

127.0.1.1   www.letscompete.it
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was at my server.xml file by changing the path field

from

Context docBase="letscompete" path="/abc" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:letscompete"/>

to

Context docBase="letscompete" path="/letscompete" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:letscompete"/>